# How to create a file with a hebrew name using python 2.7?

Tags: python, windows, encoding, io

Here is my code (t.name holds a Hebrew name):

```
# -*- coding: utf8 -*-  
                title = '%s.html' % t.name
                with file(title, 'wb') as fpo:
                    fpo.write('<meta charset="utf-8">\n')                    
                    message = 'שלום לך %s' % t.name
                    fpo.write('%s\n' % message)
```

Here is how the file looks in the file system (windows 7):
[image: Hebrew File Name]

The content is presented fine by the browser.

What am I missing here?

Thanks,
Omer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Windows filesystem uses UTF16 encoding. Your best bet is to use *unicode* values instead though, as Python will automatically use the correct codecs and APIs for your platform to encode filenames:

```
title = u'%s.html' % t.name.decode('utf8')  # decode from UTF8, use a unicode literal
with file(title, 'wb') as fpo:
    fpo.write('<meta charset="utf-8">\n')                    
    message = 'שלום לך %s' % t.name
    fpo.write('%s\n' % message)
```

Answer (score 0):

try with `title=u'%s.html' % t.name`

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @Arpit I'm not on windows. I can't try the solution even if I think it should work. And I proposed a solution, not a critique nor a request for clarification. BTW Martijn answered with details on this. :)